# Change mask starting frame

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I'm adding a mask to a video but the mask starts at frame 626 (that's where the video was so I could see the changes live) so the mask works as long as I put it in absolute mode. If I change it to relative mode, it doesn't work.

So, how can I move all the inserted keys of the mask to the first frame?

As in the image below, instead of starting at 626, it should start at 1 (or 0)

[image: Image 1]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the Start Frame to 626 (which was the frame I wanted the mask to start) under Mask Settings on the UV/Image Editor.